# Only allow owner to delete file in shared network drive Windows

Tags: windows, network-share

Im having a problem with sharing drive in my office. The problem if we have a computer to share folder so all workers can upload and save file to it. But we want to prevent workers to delete other's files. We tried to deny delete permission from security tab but that disallowed users to rename and save Word documents files. So my question is: How to only allow the user who uploaded the file to shared network drive delete it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to grant rename permissions, but not delete, in NTFS?](https://serverfault.com/questions/408572/is-it-possible-to-grant-rename-permissions-but-not-delete-in-ntfs)

Comment: Try full creator owner full rights applied to files only, and create / read / execute on the folder to all users.

Comment: Not a duplicate.  The OP wants to allow users to delete and rename their own files, but only their own files.  Not the same thing as being allowed to rename files but not to delete them.

Comment: Important clarification: do you want to allow *user A* to rename a file belonging to *user B*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I've figured this out.  Here's what you need to do:

- Assign all permissions except `Delete` and `Delete subfolders and files` (I do not believe you have to Deny them, just don't Allow them) to `Everyone`
- Assign `Full Control` to `OWNER RIGHTS`

This will do the following:

- Allow all users to modify all other users' files
- Allow all users to create new files
- Allow all users to delete and rename files that they created (files that they own)
- Prohibit all users from deleting or renaming files that others users created (files that they do not own)

Answer (score 1):

This is by (NTFS) design. If you rename, you delete the original file on the file system and create a new one with your content but a different name. You won't be able to change that behaviour. Maybe you should rather change your workflows.

Edit: found a similar Q here [Is it possible to grant rename permissions, but not delete, in NTFS?](https://serverfault.com/questions/408572/is-it-possible-to-grant-rename-permissions-but-not-delete-in-ntfs)

Comment: This is focusing on the wrong part of the question.  The OP doesn't mind if users can delete their own files, they just shouldn't be able to delete other people's files.

Answer (score -3):

As per my knowledge, you have to configure special permissions. But in windows Environment you have to give permission for folder, not for files. Otherwise you have to setup FSRM Feature.