# Prevent deletion of other's files on a shared folder

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, network-share, windows-10, file-permissions

We have a shared folder so all employees can upload and save file or create folders to it. But we want to prevent workers to delete other's files and folders. I assigned all permissions except "**Delete**" and "**Delete subfolders and files**" to **"The folder, subfolders and files"**. But this does not work. Should I add more permissions?

Answer (score 0):

https://serverfault.com/a/975978/601735

Jim Ryans's answer works perfect. In addition to his answer,  if you want to prevent others delete the files you created, just add a "file only" "deny" and tick "Create Folders/Append Data".